# Why when drawing a line with the mouse on the terrain in some places it's not drawing anything?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i want to do is a free drawing so when i move the mouse around it will draw one continuous/consecutive line also with curves. But in some places on the terrain it's not drawing and also in some places on high lands/hills it's not drawing all the time. Even if i move the mouse slow.

LineRenderer component and the script are attached to the Camera. Not Main Camera but a new Camera.

I tried before also using:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
```

But same problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLinesWithMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<Vector3> pointsList;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        pointsList = new List<Vector3>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        //if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
        if (Physics.Raycast(GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition),out hit))
        {
            Vector3 hitpoint = hit.point;
            pointsList.Add(hitpoint);

            if (pointsList.Count > 1)
                DrawLine(pointsList[pointsList.Count - 2], pointsList[pointsList.Count - 1], Color.red, 0.2f);
        }
    }

    void DrawLine(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color, float duration = 0.2f)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();
        myLine.transform.position = start;
        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.startColor = color;
        lr.startWidth = 3f;
        lr.endWidth = 3f;
        lr.SetPosition(0, start);
        lr.SetPosition(1, end);
        //GameObject.Destroy(myLine, duration);
    }
}
```

[image: Line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physics related code should generally speaking be inside FixedUpdate instead of Update.

Experienced an error earlier myself where if I Raycasted inside Update instead of FixedUpdate, it would miss its target at times without moving the cursor.

So try move the code into FixedUpdate.

Comment: Tried now but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Does the same issue occur on a flat plane?

Try make a Plane 3d object.

EDIT: accidentally hit enter....

"The Line Renderer component takes an array of two or more points in 3D space, and draws a straight line between each one."

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html

Perhaps the terrains height is in the way?

Comment: I tried on a Plane same thing. I noticed that if i move the mouse to the right or left directly it's making straight line. But one i'm little moving the mouse down or up it's making space/distance. My guess is that it's like instantiating cubes for example it does not know how to make curve/rotate it according to the mouse movement. When i did the same thing with instantiating cubes i had the same problem. instantiating straight cubes with the mouse movement is fine but when moving the mouse around it did same spaces/distances between the cubes.

Comment: That is my guess but not sure.  Maybe i should find a way to draw with curves. Not seems easy.

Comment: From the documentation for LineRenderer:

Corner Vertices and End Cap Vertices look relevant If it's just the switch from one direction to the next causing trouble, you could try play a bit with those variables.

Also take a look at this:

"Alignment  Set to View to make the line face the Camera, or Local to align it based on the orientation of its Transform component."

I assume it should be set to Local?

Comment: In the LineRenderer component if i uncheck the Use World Space property then it will draw the line perfect but then it will draw it in the air and not on the terrain. Also the mouse cursor will not be on the line front.

Comment: Changing the Alignment property from View to Local didn't help. So i changed it back to View. Only unchecking Use World Space make it drawing smooth line but in the air not on the terrain.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/442581/how-to-draw-a-grid-over-parts-of-the-terrain.html

In this link they use the heightmap information of the terrain to help alleviate the grid they make so it's on top of the terrain.

Perhaps you could try something similar?